# Electric Field Topology in a Wire

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, voltage

**1. How is the electric field set up in a wire by a battery so that we can  assume that potential at a node is constant? 
2. What happens to the electric field across a resistance which makes voltage 'drop'?**

---

Assume the following circuit:

[image: s]

The battery sets up some electric field throughout the wire, with a component along (parallel to) the wire (otherwise, there is no current). Zooming into the wire, [image]

Here I display only the component of the electric field and electron velocity that is along the wire. As the electron moves a distance *d*, the work done on it by the electric field is *Eqd*. This work is non-zero. In other words, electric potential energy of the electron varies with the distance it travels along the wire - and thus so does potential. How, then, is potential on a node the same?

---

Now, add a resistive load:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEb]

The potential at all points on the wire above the battery is 10V, below it - 0V. Considering the above - how is this so?

---

**NOTE:** I am aware that a non-ideal wire has resistance. My question lies with what resistance has to do with a difference in potentials in the first place - and why voltage drop is not CAUSED BY a charge's distance from the terminals of the battery.

---

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon since your wires have internal e-fields and therefore are resistive, it would clarify explanations if you replace your wires with chains of resistors of small value (perhaps 0.001 Ohms.)  That way your wire has numerous nodes with slightly different voltages, as occurs with all real-world wires.

Answer (score 0):

In your first circuit (no 100-ohm resistor), the potential **does** vary along the length of the wire. As was explained in the answers to your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340221/complete-wire-nonsense).

In the second circuit (with 100-ohm resistor) it also varies along the length of the wire, but the variation will be less than a millivolt if you choose an adequately sized wire. This small change is often insignificant in understanding the circuit operation, so we make an approximation that there is no potential difference between the two ends of each wire.

> How, then, is potential on a node the same?

In the first circuit you simply can't treat the wire as defining a node with the same potential at all points, since, obviously the potential at one end of the wire is different from the potential at the other end because they're connected to the two terminals of a voltage source.

In the second circuit, the potential is approximately the same at all points on each wire because the amount of potential drop is much smaller than other potential drops in the loop, and it doesn't play any significant role in understanding the circuit.

> What happens to the electric field across a resistance which makes voltage 'drop'?

In a resistor, there can be an electric field present and only a finite current will flow. Since there is a field present (and we're working in the lumped circuit regime where there's no EMF generated by magnetic fields around our circuit), the potential difference across the resistor can be found as 
$$V_{ab} = - \int_b^a \vec{E}\cdot{\rm d}\vec\ell$$

Comment: This is assuming a "real" wire which has some internal resistance. The central difficulty last time this was posted was that the wires were assumed ideal, and ideal wires actually DO have constant potential across them.

Comment: @probably_someone, I don't see anywhere in the previous question or this one where OP says the wire is assumed ideal. They ask about a conclusion we often make from assuming a wire is ideal, but that doesn't mean they understand the assumption that was made to get there. Which is why I tried to explain that assumption and how it leads to the conclusion.

Comment: Oh wait, you're the same guy from last time too. Sorry about that. I just worry that since the convention in most textbooks is to assume that all wires are ideal, it might confuse things more in the future if we neglect to make the distinction.